# All the messages Sent are not Acknowledged RabbitMQ-Blocked Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have sent around 500 messages to an exchange in RabbitMQ.Only 8 of them are processed by the application while 492 of them are not acknowledged.
There are 40 concurrent listeners to the exchange which am posting to.

The logs are as follows:

[taskExecutor-16] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-cydNATSoJE9VYDXDxdS3og=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,30), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-19] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-_tAOgctllmGebYliKjCwPw=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,25), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-6] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-MV9tAhL5QbhtTSOJACziHQ=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,39), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-30] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-SG1nB33uxABsAry7jsc6sw=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,24), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-12] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-MOY_QKujE_JiiNLn9gn7AQ=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,34), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-35] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-BcKYuEPnscByD-h-3NpW3Q=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,12), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-27] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-O2d1WsSE-qHKhhZPu-plSg=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,23), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

02:24:49.130 [taskExecutor-18] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-vO9zIyE_t2zBdEElKW4R6w=Q102}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,28), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

What are the settings to be done to avoid blocking queue issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What `blocking queue issue` ? If you see nothing more in the logs, it means the threads are blocked in your listener code. You need to edit your question to show your configuration as well as the queue topology. `...40 concurrent listeners to the exchange...` listeners listen to queues, not exchanges. More details please.

Comment: There is a binding between queue(Q102 as specified in the logs) and exchange...There are no exceptions in the logs ... "mq.min.concurrent.consumer":"40",
                "mq.max.concurrent.consumer":"100",
                "mq.core.pool.size":"40",
                "mq.max.pool.size":"100",
                "mq.queue.capacity":"1000",
                "mq.shutdown.timeout":"1000",
                "mq.receive.timeout":"60000",
                "mq.prefetch":"80",

Comment: Don't put config in comments; they are not easy to read; edit the question instead, and provide __complete__ configuration. I have no idea what these parameters are; they seem to be a mixture of task executor and listener container configuration. I need to see all the relevant configuration not just what you "think" I need. As I said, if there is nothing more in the logs, it means these 8 threads are likely stuck in your user code. `jstack` will tell you what they are doing.

Comment: @GaryRussell...Thanks for the update..will edit the question with the required configurations ...Will use jstack and debug the application